# Qt: equivalent to getch() for utf-8 characters

Tags: c++, qt

I'm looking for a function in Qt that does the same thing as `getch()` form `conio.h`, because i want to read utf-8 characters from the terminal.

I've come across this Thread https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1418670, where someone asked the same question and someone mentioned that `bool QIODevice::getChar(char *c)` exists.

However as QIODevice is abstract, how would I call this function? Or is there any better alternative?

Comment: Have you try with [QFile](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfile.html) with `stdin` or [QTextStream](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextstream.html) with `stdin` and `setCodec` ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure your terminal itself works in UTF-8 encoding:

```
QTextStream in(stdin);
in.setCodec("UTF-8");

// read character
QChar ch;
in >> ch;  

// read line
QString input = in.readLine();
```

Comment: I'd like an alternative to getch() as I want to get the character as soon as it is typed instead of waiting for '\n' to be typed. Thank you nonetheless.